# Dart secure connection with private key: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE

Tags: java, flutter, dart

I have a site certificate ('tls_connection_cert') for TSL connection and a private certificate ('private_cert.p12') for authentication. Whenever I want to make connection in dart I get an error SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE(tls_record.cc:586) with no extra information.
Dart code:

```
SecurityContext context = new SecurityContext(withTrustedRoots: true)
  ..setTrustedCertificates('tls_connection_cert')
  ..usePrivateKey('private_cert.p12', password: 'password');

  await SecureSocket.connect(
      "service_host", 9002, context: context, onBadCertificate: _onSelfSignedCertificate).then((socket) {
    print('Connected to: '
        '${socket.remoteAddress.address}:${socket.remotePort}');
    socket.destroy();
  });
```

I already uses his service with a JAVA code which work perfectly, with no errors. The service in question is already used by the java code for 3 years now.
Java code:

```
    KeyManager[] privateCert; // private_cert.p12
TrustManager[] publicCert; // tls_connection_cert
SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ssl.init(privateCert.getKeyManagers(), publicCert.getTrustManagers(), null);
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)ssl.getSocketFactory().createSocket("service_host", 9002);
socket.startHandshake();
socket.close();
```

Online service only allow TLSv1.2. Project is a Flutter project build in Android Studio on Windows 10 machine.
How can I found what’s wrong with dart code?

Comment: What do you have in `_onSelfSignedCertificate`? Generally, the best way to diagnose this is to get a packet capture and look at it in, say, wireshark. See which end sends the TLS alert. The previous message is likely the culprit. Is the Dart end sending the client cert?

Comment: I have probe with Wireshark and found the point of failure. It's right after successful exchange of Hello calls between server and client. Client is sending »Encrypted Handshake Message« to the server and server is responding with Handshake Failure. TLS connection is successful, so I suspect private key encryption is problematic. Dart is sending client cert and the _onSelfSignedCertificate is actually not needed since I provide trusted certificate in security context

Comment: Try comparing the packet capture of Dart and Java connecting? Which cipher suite does the server choose in the Server Hello? Does the certificate chain sent by the client look the same in both cases? Try with just a standalone Dart command line application too.

Comment: Thanks for help. I think I finally understand the problem now: On Dart the ClientHello is initiated with protocol TLS 1.0 and for ServerHello is used Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d). Online service only permits TLS 1.2. On Java side ClientHello is initiated with TLS 1.2 and ServerHello selected Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009f) – not the same as Dart version. Selected chipper is only available on TLS1.2. So the question is: Is it possible to set TLS1.2 as default protocol when starting secure connection?

Comment: Using vanilla `dart:io` in a standalone app, Dart sends a 1.2 Client Hello inside a 1.0 header, offering 15 cipher suites. The server I'm using replies with a 1.2 server hello inside a 1.2 header, and picks `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256`, certificate etc. Dart sends a 1.2 client key exchange etc in 1.2 headers. It's not clear to me if Dart uses its own implementation when running on Android, or delegates to the platform. Certainly the `dart:io` version happily makes 1.2 connections.

Comment: Same happens in my case. Client Hello is 1.0 header with 15 chipers. On Java side is 1.2 header with 45 chipers. Service I call is EU service with strict TLS1.2 policy that is out of my control. I guess that’s the reason why server can’t pick strong enough chipper. I wish I could set minimum allowed protocol like in other languages. Since this will be flutter application I could use Platform channel to make native call, but this kind of defeat purpose of flutter app.

Comment: @user3428555 Did you find a solution for your problem? Did you manage to set TLS 1.2 as the protocol?